# Check if a particular time is in a range in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes having different time interval: first one is every 3 hours; the 2nd one is every 15mins. I want to write a 'for' loop, something like this

```
for(time in levels(15mins interval), e.g. (00:00,00:15,00:30,...){  
    if(time is between 3h interval, e.g. 00:15 is between 00:00 and 03:00){  
         regress 00:15 data onto 00:00 and 03:00 data
      }else{regress 00:00 data in 2nd data frame onto 00:00 data in 1st data frame}
```

I don't know how to implement this. Is there a way to compare the time?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way, may not be perfect. Produce a dataframe of two columns: 1st column is 1:96, 2nd column is the 15min time interval; and make use of the modulus operation.

```
df_time=data.frame(cbind(index=1:96, time=levels(df1$time)))
for(ind in 1:96){
    if(ind %% 12 ==1){
        do something with df_time[ind,2]
    }else{
        tim1=df_time[ind %/% 12 +1 , 2]
        tim2=df_time[ind %/% 12 +13, 2]
        do something with tim1 & tim2
     }}
```